# How to fix Out-of-bounds access (OVERRUN) error

Tags: c++, coverity

I ran the coverity analysis tool on my c++ code and it is showing me "overrun-buffer-arg" warning when calling copy().

What is overrun buffer and how can I solve it?

Here's my code snippet-

```
    if ( itr == m_unloadAppFunctions->end())
    {
        CallbackFunc *cFunc = new CallbackFunc();
        std::string *tmpS = new std::string;
        tmpS->copy( const_cast <char*> ( callbackType->c_str()), std::string::npos);
        cFunc->callbackType = tmpS;
        cFunc->functionPtr = functionPtr;
        m_unloadAppFunctions->insert(appFunctions::value_type(callbackFunctionTag, cFunc));
    }
```

Screenshot from coverity tool-

[image: Coverity issue:-]

Comment: Looks like Coverity is not aware of the option to pass `std::string::npos` as `count` to `std::string::copy`.

Comment: As @wohlstad said, it seems that it's a false positive. So I guess you would want to suppress it: https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Suppressing-False-Positive-Intentional-defects

Comment: Why `std::string *` and not `std::string`? Also, `copy` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: To be more specific, `string_a.copy(pointer, std::string::npos)` copies `string_a.size()` characters *from* `string_a` *to* `pointer`. Just use `std::string` and `cFunc->callbackType = callbackType;`.